# Join tables and fetch from Many to many (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

User Table

```
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          id         |     email        |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |     3               |   18             |
    |---------------------|------------------|
```

Post Table

```
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |     id              |     Title        |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |     12              |   My Post        |
    |---------------------|------------------|
```

Category Table

```
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |     id              |     Title        |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |     18              |   My Category    |
    |---------------------|------------------|
```

Category-Post

```
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |     post_id         |     category_id  |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |     12              |   18             |
    |---------------------|------------------|
```

User-Category

```
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |     user_id         |     category_id  |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |     3               |   18             |
    |---------------------|------------------|
```

In this table structure, I want to fetch all the post with any given user id, according to their favorite category, with a single query.

I have defined the relations for all the models

Category:

```
public function posts(){

     $this->belongsToMany(Post::class,'category-post','category_id','post_id')
}
```

Post:

```
public function categories(){

     $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category-post','post_id','category_id')
}
```

User:

```
public function favCategories(){
         $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'user-category-','user_id','category_id')
    }
```

Comment: First of all you need to define relationships.

Comment: I have edited the question. can you see that again ...

Comment: Hi @adh.ranjan if my answer is helpful, please approved my answer.

Comment: Sure, when I reach office and try with it

Comment: Hi @adh.ranjan remove '-' after 'user-category' from **User** model

Comment: Try $data = User::with("favCategories.posts.categories")->find($user_id);

Answer (score 3):

Can try this with your relationship model

`$data = User::with("favCategories.categories.posts")->find($user_id);`

// "favCategories" get first of all favourite categories

// "categories" get all category

// "posts" get all post with these categories wise

Answer (score -1):

Here is the single eloquent query:

```
<?php
dd($posts = User::find(3) //user id 3
->categories()->where('id', 18) //favorite category id 18
->posts);
```

Comment: Why down voted? The question is "fetch all the post with any given user id, according to their favorite category, with a single query". So in the answer "given user id" is 3, "favorite category" is 18, and it is a charming "single query" :D If the problem is returning comma separated titles only, just finish the statement with ->posts (with no parenthesis) and use it with foreach loop...